# Combine Mulltiple CSV files periodically using first file table header cmd

Tags: excel, csv

I am trying to make a reporting file. At the end of every month a CSV file is downloaded from Snapengage (company service chat). I used:

```
cd C:\Users\****\****\****\SnapEngage Raw
copy *.csv combined.csv
```

This worked fine but I want to only use the header from the first file and only keep the data rows from the rest.

I tried using this refering to this site and several others.

```
cd C:\Users\****\****\****\SnapEngage Raw
copy *.csv combined.csv
@echo off
ECHO Set working directory
cd /d %~dp0
ECHO Deleting existing combined file
echo '' > combined.csv
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set cnt=1
for %%i in (*.csv) do (
  if cnt==1 (
    for /f "delims=/" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  ) else (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  )
  set /a cnt+=1
)
```

When I run it it gets stuck on "deleting combined file". I want to be able to combine the CSV files and then edit them adding a unique ID column. So I can link this with the tracking excel sheet.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you don't receive answers here, you may want to search or ask on one of two other sites of the Stack Exchange network: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). The latter is more system administrator oriented.

Comment: what language are you looking to do this in - your tagging could be better.

Comment: Sorry first time poster. The file is in english but most of the computers are german. I have however set the first line of the CSV file to sep=, to override any of the reigonal settings.